# Java : naming convention for accessors

Tags: java, naming-conventions

I'm looking for the official naming convention in Java regarding accessors.

I've seen that, for instance, the `JPanel` class deprecated the `size()` method in favor of `getSize()`.

But in the `ArrayList` class, the method is `size()`.

So I'm wondering if accessors should be named `getXXX()` or `xXX()` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's usually a bad idea to **not** use the **JavaBeans convention** (getters and setters).
They're used through reflection by many frameworks, in particular with *EL* where sometimes you can't access your fields without the rights getters (depending on the EL flavour).

So your accessors should always be named `getXxx()` or `isXxx()` and `setXxx()`.

`size()` in the collection framework is an example of "flaw" which can annoy developers (see link below). The choice made by Josh Bloch and Neal Gafter to make it more readable now makes it difficult to obtain in some contexts (EL).

But remember the JavaBeans convention isn't the Java naming convention.

---

**Resources :**

- [How to Access the Size of a Collection in a JSP Page Using JSTL-EL](http://blog.smartkey.co.uk/2009/01/how-to-access-the-size-of-a-collection-in-a-jsp-page-using-jstl-el/)
- [Java conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html)
- [JavaBeans](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/index.html)
- [JavaBeans specification](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html)

**On the same topic :**

- [Getters on an immutable type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680189/getters-on-an-immutable-type)

Comment: (+1) I'm amused that the [*Naming* Conventions page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367) is titled "NO TITLE", heh.

Answer (score 3):

With query methods, I always look at `getXXX` as something that is provided versus something that is calculated. The `size()` method returns the size of the collection which is a derived value, so it makes sense. If you had `getSize()` my assumption would be that I could somehow set the size (through a constructor or setter method).

Comment: You make a good point but I would say `getSize()` makes more sense compared to `size()` can be considered a (albeit virtual) property of a `List` since it has always a size assigned to it.

Answer (score 1):

For anything trying to look like a JavaBean, it should be `getXXX` or `isXXX`. (I can't remember whether hasXXX is valid for Boolean properties as well... not sure.)

It makes sense to treat a `JPanel` in a bean kind of way - for designers etc - but not an `ArrayList`.

Personally I *tend* to use the getXXX form just for consistency, but I believe the above is the reasoning involved in `ArrayList`'s naming.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a formative addentum to Colin HERBERT's answer which, in my opinion, is enough:

- *Accessor* method signatures should always look like `public Type getProperty()`. Additionally, accessors should always return a **copy** of the property's value, not the value itself.
- *Mutator* method signatures should always look like `public void setProperty(Type value)`

Combining an *accessor* and a *mutator* gives you a JavaBean property. JavaBeans are not considered to be immutable by nature, but if you want to make it immutable, you should use the following signature for the *mutator* method: `public YourJavaBean withProperty(Type value)`. Note that this should always return a completely new `YourJavaBean` instance with copied property values.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse the convention is definitely to use the `get`pattern. The automisation tools create and handle getters by checking for and writing `get` and `set` style accessors.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the `get`/`is`/`set`-Convention (especially for ValueObjects/DataObjects) not only because it's the *JavaBeans* specification but because of the following two points.

1. The clear prefix of the method seperates property related methods from 'logic' methods.
2. You can use it out of the box with JSP and other frameworks that assume this naming.

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to follow setXXX and getXXX pattern as per JavaBeans specification.  The size() method named so, may be as it is just querying the state.