# Is 'public Boolean isBikeTyreFlat()' a valid JavaBeans method signature?

Tags: java, object, boolean, return

Is this method signature valid?

```
public Boolean isBikeTyreFlat(){}
```

Note that I am trying to return an Object not a primitive here.

Thanks :)

Comment: Why don't you try this in your code.

Comment: Sorry... I know this will work, but is it a valid against the javabean naming standards?

Comment: You should edit your question with that piece of information and look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698171/java-naming-convention-for-accessors.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In JavaBeans, the getter method for `boolean` can be `getXXX()` or `isXXX()`. Since `Boolean` is not a primitive type, a `getXXX()` is required. The `isXXX()` is only for the boolean primitive type (thanks @Kemoda).

Refer to [section 8.3.2 of the JavaBeans Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/).

Comment: per the propertydescriptor spec isXXX only works for primitive boolean

Comment: @Kemoda, Had to create a test case and you're right. I've updated my question accordingly.

Comment: yes, i know it because it bite me recently, i was forced to refactor all my boolean getters to the "get" form in some of the layers of my apps.

Answer (score 1):

In strict JavaBeans, this is a valid name (see the answer of @TheEliteGentleman).

However, please make sure you are not doing something like this:

```
public class BikeTyre {
    private boolean flat;
    public Boolean isBikeTyreFlat() {
        return flat;
    }
}
```

This is not recommended, since the name of your field does not match the method name. Some frameworks allow adding annotations to both the internal Field and the getter/setter of a Java Bean; the mismatch could confuse these frameworks. Please also note that it is bad practice to add the class name to your field; your method should just be `isFlat()`.

Of course, this is perfectly valid:

```
public class Unicycle {
    private boolean bikeTyreFlat;
    public Boolean isBikeTyreFlat() {
        return bikeTyreFlat;
    }
}
```

But then again, are you really modelling unicycles? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I have to disagree with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10189265/953327). I had this same question and wrote a quick test.

Given the JavaBean as:

```
package example;

public class FooBean {

    private Boolean published;

    public void setPublished(Boolean published) {
        this.published = published;
    }

    public Boolean isPublished() {
        return published;
    }

}
```

And a Main class that looks like:

```
package example;

import java.beans.BeanInfo;
import java.beans.IntrospectionException;
import java.beans.Introspector;
import java.beans.PropertyDescriptor;

public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {



        BeanInfo beanInfo = null;
        try {
            beanInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(FooBean.class);
        } catch (IntrospectionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        PropertyDescriptor[] propertyDescriptors = beanInfo.getPropertyDescriptors();

        for(PropertyDescriptor descriptor : propertyDescriptors){
            System.out.println("descriptor: " + descriptor);
            System.out.println("descriptor.getName(): " + descriptor.getName());
            System.out.println("descriptor.getReadMethod(): " + descriptor.getReadMethod());
        }

    }

}
```

The result of running the main class is:

```
descriptor: java.beans.PropertyDescriptor@1e746992
descriptor.getName(): class
descriptor.getReadMethod(): public final native java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()
descriptor: java.beans.PropertyDescriptor@c994fbad
descriptor.getName(): published
descriptor.getReadMethod(): null
```

If I change `FooBean.java` to look like this:

```
package example;

public class FooBean {

    private boolean published;

    public void setPublished(boolean published) {
        this.published = published;
    }

    public boolean isPublished() {
        return published;
    }

}
```

Then the resulting output is:

```
descriptor: java.beans.PropertyDescriptor@18072768
descriptor.getName(): class
descriptor.getReadMethod(): public final native java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()
descriptor: java.beans.PropertyDescriptor@1e2ff4ad
descriptor.getName(): published
descriptor.getReadMethod(): public boolean example.FooBean.isPublished()
```

This tells me that for it to be a valid JavaBeans signature, the type must be declared a primitive boolean value.

**Edit**
Upon further testing it appears that just the declared return type of the isXxx() method must be boolean for JavaBeans to recognize it:

```
package example;

public class FooBean {

    private Boolean published;

    public void setPublished(Boolean published) {
        this.published = published;
    }

    public boolean isPublished() {
        return published;
    }

}
```

Result:

```
descriptor: java.beans.PropertyDescriptor@1e746992
descriptor.getName(): class
descriptor.getReadMethod(): public final native java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()
descriptor: java.beans.PropertyDescriptor@f96377e5
descriptor.getName(): published
descriptor.getReadMethod(): public boolean example.FooBean.isPublished()
```

Comment: Your `Edit` section contradicts the very first statement which states: `I have to disagree with the accepted answer.`. :-)

Comment: @BuhakeSindi I have updated it to refer to the actual answer I was referring to :)